# NodeJS and AngularJS genereted corrupted files

Tags: node.js, angularjs, zip

I'm having problems downloading files, my data comes from an API (NodeJS + Express).
The xlsx files are simply corrupted and do not open, as do those in zip format.
Some xlsx have strange characters like:

��Ӫ��E���Q^���3�3�ϾhwR-��vY!c�O�y�����I�㱣�eG������[J�Gߌw������ES��lz�e�L�'Sr��`x2�R��Į��¦

Here is my NodeJS code (method that returns data to the front):

```
public async downloadFile(patch: string, start: [number, number], timeout: number) {
        try {
            ...

            const buffer: any = [];
            let readStream;
            const downloadPromise = new Promise((resolve, _reject, onCancel) => {
                onCancel(() => {
                    if (readStream) readStream.destroy();
                    return;
                });
                // create the read stream and register events callbacks
                readStream = this.bucket.file(storageInfo.$path).createReadStream();
                readStream.on('error', err => {
                    readStream.destroy();
                    resolve({ downloaded: false, data: err });
                });
                readStream.on('data', data => {
                    buffer.push(data);
                });
                readStream.on('end', () => {
                    readStream.destroy();
                    resolve({ downloaded: true, data: Buffer.concat(buffer) });
                });
            });

            return Response.success({ file: storageInfo, buffer: result.data });

        } catch (ex) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Angularjs code:

```
public async previewFileFromGoogleStorage(hash: string): Promise<IFileDownload> {
    try {
        if (!hash) return null;

        const operation = await this.$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `${this.getUrlDownload()}${hash}`,
            cache: false,
            timeout: this.timeout,
            responseType: "arraybuffer"
        });
        
        const response: angular.IHttpResponse<any> = operation;
        const parsedReponse = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(response.data));
        const resultFile = <IDownloadParamsReturn>parsedReponse.data;

        const file = resultFile.file;
        const buffer = resultFile.buffer.data;

        const fileName = file.fileName;
        const fileBuffer = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        const fileType = this.getContentType(file.fileType);
        const fileBlob = new Blob([fileBuffer], { type: fileType });
        const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
        const result = <IFileDownload> { url: fileURL, name: fileName, type: fileType, blob: fileBlob };

        return result;

    } catch (ex) {
        HandleError.exception(ex);
    }
}

private async sendToDownload(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        this.$scope.file = <IFileDownload>await this.downloadService.previewFileFromGoogleStorage(hash);

        if (this.$scope.file.type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
            this.$scope.type = 'image';
            this.previewImage();
        } else if (this.$scope.file.type === 'application/pdf') {
            this.$scope.type = 'pdf';
            this.previewPdf();
        } else {
            this.$scope.type = 'other';
            const self = this;

            this.$scope.$apply(function () {
                self.blockUI.stop();
                self.downloadFile();
            });
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        this.blockUI.stop();
        HandleError.exception(ex);
    }
}

private downloadFile(): void {
    if (this.$rootScope.isIE) {
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(this.$scope.file.blob, this.$scope.file.name);
    } else {
        let link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([this.$scope.file.blob], { type: this.$scope.file.blob.type }));
        link.download = this.$scope.file.name;
        link.click();
    }
}
```

I'm stuck with this problem and I don't know what to do, I've already tried changing the content-type to "blob" or simply not using it, but didnt work.

Comment: The function of downloadFile is precisely to return data to the front. The file is returned as Buffer. The strangest thing is that I can't even open the zip files, just like the xlsx.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what do you mean.

Comment: And do you have any suggestions on how to avoid this error?